# How to populate a dataGridView with an IQueryable

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, iqueryable

I've added required columns and with right DataPropertyName s and I use following code to populate a datagridview. However, my dataGridView Shows columnheaders and one empty row only. What is wrong with my code?

```
public static IQueryable<Kolon> kolonlistele()
{
    using (Pehlivan.pehkEntities ctx = new Pehlivan.pehkEntities())
    {
        var result = from k in ctx.Kolons
                     select k;

        return result;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = veritabani_islemleri.kolonlistele();
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `dataGridView1.DataBind()` and/or `.kolonlistele().ToList()`

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: .ToList() works. But that is not what I want. I want to be able to update data on the dataGridView.

Comment: Ah.. yes. I was thinking WebForms with the Databind call. @Servy has explained why .ToList works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is delayed execution.  `result` isn't actually a result.  It's not the results of the query, it's just the query itself.  That's what an `IQueryable` is.  You can think of it as just a complex version of the SQL query, rather than the result set.  The actual query won't be executed until you iterated over it or use some method that does iterate over it.  (For example calling `ToList`, putting it in a `foreach`, or as is the case here, binding it to a `DataGridView`).

This delayed execution is particularly problematic here because there is a disposable resource involved.  You aren't actually executing the query until you're outside of the `using` block, which means that the `DataSource` has been disposed by the time you actually are trying to execute the query.

One way to solve this problem would be to just eagerly execute the query:

```
public static IQueryable<Kolon> kolonlistele()
{
    using (Pehlivan.pehkEntities ctx = new Pehlivan.pehkEntities())
    {
        return ctx.Kolons.ToList();
    }
}
```

By calling `ToList` *inside* of the `using` the query is executed before the data source is disposed.  Also note I removed the `from k in ctx.Kolons select k` because it's not actually accomplishing anything; it's entirely redundant.

Your other option would be to increase the scope of the data source.  If, instead of declaring it inside of the `kolonlistele` method the data source was declared at a "higher scope" such that the data source was set while the object was not yet disposed then it would also work.  This would be more appropriate in situations where the data source is more expensive to create, or when the size of the query is so large that it's important to stream it (if you need to stream the data then eagerly evaluating it into a `List` would be a problem).

Comment: I got your point. So can you tell me a way to populate datagridview and be able to update the data right on the datagridview?

Comment: @HasanAyan That would be an example of a time where you would need to use the second solution I mentioned; you would need to increase the scope of the datacontext so that it won't be disposed until you're done using it.  If you want to be using the same one for updates then it might mean making it an instance field and disposing of it manually in the `Form` dispose method rather than through a `using`.

Comment: I have done what u have said.I am not disposing it right now. But it shows no data if I do not call .ToList()